# How to save a Google Street View static image to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, google-street-view-static-api

When I open a link like this in the browser to the Google Street View Static API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=fifth%20avenue&key=...
```

It works as it should for me, and I see the picture.

My question is how I save it to my Firebase Storage?

Normally when my users upload their own image, I write something like:

```
storage.child('images/' + filename).put(file, {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
});
```

How can I upload an image directly from Street View Static API instead?

Comment: If you want to upload anything at all to Storage, you have to upload the entire content from your app.  There is no client API for uploading the contents of some URL without first downloading it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you provide me with a name or a link to documentation of that clienet API?

Comment: I corrected my comment - there is **no** such api.